# $(window.document).ready(function () { ... } not really ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following window.open (url is same host/domain as current page):

```
function openWindow() {
   var fswin = window.open(url, msg);
   $(fswin.document).ready(function () {
      setWindowTitle(fswin, msg)   //set window title
   });
}
```

At times I am getting an error either null / undefined trying to set the title or fs_date value below:

```
function setWindowTitle(fswin, fs_date) {
    if ((fswin.document.title !== undefined) && (fswin.document.getElementById("fs_date") !== undefined))
    {
        fswin.document.title = fs_date;
        fswin.document.getElementById("fs_date").value = fs_date;
    }
    else //if not loaded yet wait a 50ms then try again
    {
        setTimeout(setWindowTitle, 50); //wait 50ms and check again
    }
}
```

It is an intermittent error works sometimes not other times;
seems to me I can not use setTimeout(setWindowTitle, 50) because it will not pass in the require parameters to setWindow(fswin, fs_date)? Maybe that is the problem it is hitting setTimeout(...) sometimes and therefore does not pass in fswin and fs_date?

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: As for your issue with `setTimeout`, you can use: `setTimeout(function() { setWindowTitle(fswin, fs_date); }, 50);`

Answer (score 2):

The `.ready()` method doesn't care what element it's bound to, it always operates on the current document.

Use the `load` event for other elements.

```
$(fswin).on("load", function() {
    setWindowTitle(fswin, msg);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar - I think what I really need is to wait on a hidden input value to be loaded? If I have <input type="hidden" id="hidden_id" value="" /> Can I do the following: $('#hidden_id').on("load", function()...  I need to make certain value gets filled in?

Comment: No, the `load` event only fires on elements that get loaded from remote URLs, such as windows and images. But a hidden input should be loaded when the HTML from the server is loaded.

Comment: I just corrected my answer, it should just be `$(fswin)`, not `$(fswin.document)`.

Comment: I think I am making this more difficult than I need to - basically all I want to do is use window.open to open a new html page on my site and send it a couple of values. I believe there might be a better way?

Comment: Barmar thanks for your help it led me to do more research - I am now using sessionStorage.setItem("fs_date", dt). Then in the page being opened by window.open I am using sessionStorage.getItem("fs_date") to retrieve the item fs_date. This is working I believe across multiple browsers.